# Excel conditional formatting for linked cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a an Excel spread sheet which has external links to csv files with some vlookups of other csv files. I want to conditional format cells based on the value but it's not working. I'm assuming because it's checking the field and seeing the formula not the value the formula gives you...

For example:- A field has =MySheet.csv!$A$1:$A$700 I'd like to look up "wibble" and make the box yellow".

Another one has =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,MySheet.csv!$B:$D,3,FALSE),"") I'd like to look up "wobble" and make the box orange.

Do you have to make it complicated and refer back to the original source for it to work?

Comment: The conditional formatting should relate to the value, not the formula. What formula is in the conditional formatting that you've tried?

Comment: Your [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is malformed. Please review the documentation and correct it.

Comment: Fairly basic as in colour it, based on formula ="wibble"

Comment: What's wrong with the vlookup, it works?